# With mongo_session_store-rails3, session doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having a problem with sessions in rails 3.2 when I use mongoid as SessionStore. I decided to use [Brian Hempel's](https://github.com/brianhempel/mongo_session_store) fork of `mongo_session_store` gem, as it was updated last month.

Before switching to this gem, I was using the default cookie-based session store, and it was working without problem. But now, even `flash` doesn't work when I redirect to another page. Session data seems to be reset on every single request.

And as a side-question: every request creates a new session document in db! Is it right? I'm confused. =(

I put these lines in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid', :git => 'git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
gem 'bson_ext', "~> 1.5"
gem 'mongo_session_store-rails3', '~> 3.0.5'
```

Then in my `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
SomeAppName::Application.config.session_store :mongoid_store
```

**sessions_controller.rb:**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    ...
  end
  def create
    user = User.find_by_identifier(params[:identifier])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:uid] = user._id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render :new
    end
  end
  def destroy
    ...
  end
end
```

If any other part of my code is needed, please tell me to post it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you check on your database if a session document is save or not ?

Comment: Yes. As I said, the `sessions` collection is there and for every request, a new `session` document is created inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gem author here. Version 4.0.0 was just released, which supports Mongoid 3.

```
gem 'mongo_session_store-rails3', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have similar and other issues in my project.
After changed to branch of [cubewebsites](https://github.com/cubewebsites/mongo_session_store) all works as expected.

Branch description:

**This fork aims to address a couple of issues I was having with the master branch:**

```
 <class:Session>': undefined method `collection_name=' for ActionDispatch::Session::MongoidStore::Session:Class (NoMethodError)
```

and

```
 <class:Session>': uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Session::MongoidStore::Session::BSON (NameError)
```